# Can't properly empty out a list due to "cannot increment end list iterator"

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm trying to figure out why accessing the next-to-last item in a linked list keeps crashing the program. My actual goal is to safely delete the last item of the list without a memory/iterator crash. I understand that there's a problem with `list.erase(iterator)`, which I was able to resolve by using `iterator = list.erase(iterator)` instead. Specifically, in the code below I use `i = listofpeople.erase(i)`.But now, even with that, I get errors when erase()ing the last and even the next-to-last element of the list. The error occurs in the second iteration before it gets to the third iteration.

Can someone tell me why these errors are occurring, and how to prevent them?

```
size_t remaining;
int diceroll;
list<Person> listofpeople;
typedef std::list<Person>::iterator currElem;
currElem end;
Person Pigrogromitus, Bob, Iohannes;
listofpeople.push_front(Pigrogromitus);
listofpeople.push_front(Iohannes);
listofpeople.push_front(Bob);
for (currElem i = listofpeople.begin(); i != listofpeople.end(); ++i)
{
    end = listofpeople.end();
    remaining = std::distance(i, end);
    cout << "Iterating..." << endl;
    cout << "Size is " << listofpeople.size() << endl;
    //diceroll = rand() % 100;
    if (remaining < 2)
    {
        cout << "Out of room" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    else
        i = listofpeople.erase(i);
    cout << "erased" << endl;
    cout << "Size is " << listofpeople.size() << endl;
}
cout << "Ending size of list is " << listofpeople.size();
return 0;
```

Comment: You're removing an iterator and then calling `++i` as part of the `for` control.  What did you think would happen when you accessed an erased iterator?

Comment: So you're saying I'm erasing the iterator rather than the node in the list? I want to erase the node.

Comment: `erase` invalidates the iterator.  I'm admittedly being loose with my language in the previous comment.

Comment: If you erase then use the returned iterator for the next iteration. If you don't erase then increment the current iterator for the next iteration. You cannot increment every time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12666898/920069

Comment: Your algorithm is very inefficient, as you're constantly invoking `std::distance`. All you're actually doing in this loop is removing the last person from the list, which you can do in constant time with [`pop_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_back). Or you can just use [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/resize) if you want to trim the list to a specific size.

Comment: I did not realize that an erase() invalidates the iterator. So what's the correct approach if I need to traverse the entire list and delete some elements as necessary? Set up an inner loop with its own per-traversal iterator?

Comment: _"what's the correct approach"_ -- did you read the answer that @RetiredNinja linked? A nice modern alternative is [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase2)

Comment: @GlatisantSoldier *My actual goal is to safely delete the last item of the list without a memory/iterator crash* -- `listofpeople.pop_back();`

Comment: @paddy The ultimate goal is to remove as many nodes as necessary, which may be at any location in a list of at least 12 nodes. In order to do that, I have to check each node individually for the probability of them leaving the node, and then remove them if they "decide" to leave.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. You have been given all the information that you need here, but you're still asking questions about it. Is there something unclear?

Comment: @paddy I didn't understand quite what the article was saying at first. I am going to try the example and see how it works.

Comment: *I have to check each node individually for the probability of them leaving the node* -- You don't need a loop to remove items in a container that is based on a condition.  That is already taken care of by `erase_if`.

Comment: I tried the logic in the article linked by @RetiredNinja and that emptied out my list successfully. I will try erase_if since that seems more appropriate to my needs, but the article does a good job of explaining why I was running into problems.

Comment: Modern C++ style note: `typedef std::list<Person>::iterator currElem;` => `using currElem = std::list<Person>::iterator;`